# Rpc call showing empty in evm integrated chain?

Tags: polkadot, rpc, evm, blockchain, layer0

i have been working on polkadot layer 0 chain. i have integrated evm frontier on layer 0 chain and everything is working fine .when i try to call rpc (eth.getcode) it is showing empty . can some please tell what is issue in this case .   i have tried evm integration on release 0.9.36 to release. 1.1.0 versions  and on every version i am facing this issue .[image: error]